# Displaying "Flutter Demo" instead of App's Label Name in recent apps

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My app's label name is **Inshorts Clone**, but instead of showing Inshorts Clone, it is showing **Flutter Demo** in recent apps.
How to change 'Flutter Demo'?

Here is a screenhot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main.dart`

```
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Flutter Demo', // change to Inshorts Clone
```

you can change name accordingly

Comment: @KalashSaini do you want to change the app name? this answer would only change the title inside your app, not the app name.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "DEMo ",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Add  **title: "DEMo ",**

Answer (score 0):

For `android` go to this path `android/app/src/main` and change this in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:label="Flutter Demo" 
...
>
```

For iOS go to this path `ios/Runner` and change this in `info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>Flutter Demo</string>
```

Then stop your app and build it again and you will see the changes.